# Extracting media objects present in LibreOffice Impress using LibreOffice APIs

Tags: java, api, media, libreoffice, openoffice-impress

I am trying to get details of the media contents (video, audio ) present in a LibreOffice Impress document through LibreOffice API in java. The details which I want to extract is the type of media content present in the document. And also ways to export them. I have gone through the java examples given on the Website but could not find anything relevant to type of video or audio present in file and extraction of video files. I have gone through the example given for exporting Images from Impress Documents using GraphicExportFilter, but it is not able to export video or audio files present in the document. I also tried to extract the type of media content by using XShape (code below), but it only gives the name of the media content and not its type(audio/video/or media extension).
For exporting I am also aware of the method of converting documents to pptx and then renaming and extracting all types of media files. But I suppose that would consume more time to extract (correct me if I am wrong) in practical application, so I was trying to do the same by LibreOffice API.

```
XComponent  xDrawDoc = Helper.loadDocument( xOfficeContext,fileName, "_blank", 0, pPropValues );
XDrawPage xPage = PageHelper.getDrawPageByIndex( xDrawDoc,nPageIndex );
XIndexAccess xIndexAccess = UnoRuntime.queryInterface(XIndexAccess.class,xPage); 
long shapeNumber = xIndexAccess.getCount();                        
for(int j=0;j < shapeNumber;j++) 
{ 
     XShape xShape =UnoRuntime.queryInterface(XShape.class, xPage.getByIndex(j));
     XNamed xShapeNamed =UnoRuntime.queryInterface(XNamed.class, xShape);                                           
     System.out.println(j+":"+xShapeNamed.getName());
}
```

(This code gives me the names of the media contents present in Impress but not its type or extension)

Thanks in Advance..